# Trying to find out away to remap mouse click to left CTRL button on my desktop

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

As I am aging, I am trying to find a way to avoid as much as possible now to click on my mouse because the joints in my fingers hurt more and more, possibly from rheumatoid arthritis, though I wasn't diagnosed.

I would like to remap the Left CTRL, Super_L or left ALT to simulate that the left mouse button is depressed.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one.

THank you very much.

Stepandjump is getting old!

Comment: some time ago i used a program called [evrouter](https://www.bedroomlan.org/projects/evrouter) to map mouse button presses to ctrl/alt keypresses.  you may be able to get it to handle your use case; see [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_buttons#evrouter) for config tips.  it may not be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

#### xdotool

With **xdotool** [[manpage for the `xdotool` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdotool)] we can assign any mouse event to a keyboard shortcut.

After we had installed `xdotool` with

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

we can open the system settings keyboard dialog to assign a new custom shortcut or replace an exisiting shortcut with a new command

[image]

Press <kbd>+</kbd> for a new shortcut where

```
xdotool click 1
```

is the left mouse button (`2` for middle, `3` for right button etc. see manpage). After selecting the "New Accelerator" in the list simply press the key you want the mouse click assigned to.

In case there already is a system shortcut defined to this key you may  have to remove this shortcut first (<kbd>-</kbd>).

---

#### Universal Access

Alternatively you may also want to consider using the inbuilt **Universal Access** features for the mouse from the *System Settings*:

[image]

You will find three entries to ease mouse operation:

- Control the pointer **using the keypad**: <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> move the mouse in small steps, and <kbd>5</kbd> is a left-klick.
- **Trigger a secondary click** (AKA double-click) by pressing and holding the left mouse button.
- **Hover click:** simulates a click after a defined delay on hover over a button. We can select which mouse action to assign:

  [image]